# How can I reproduce a beautiful 3D vector plot?

Tags: graphics3d, vector, physics

I am a Mathematica V8 user.

I found a very beautiful 3D vector plot on the Internet. I don't think it was created in Mathematica, but I'd like to reproduce it with Mathematica.

[image]

How to do that?

---

**EDIT**

This image originates from [an article by FZ Jülich](https://www.fz-juelich.de/SharedDocs/Meldungen/PGI/PGI-1/EN/2016/2016-10-20-Skyrmion-Characterization.html) with further details available in [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms13613) and depicts a skyrmion. In particular, the explicit parametrization of the spins is given by

```
{x, y, z} ==
  {
    Cos[m ϕ + γ] Sin[θ[r]],
    Sin[m ϕ + γ] Sin[θ[r]],
    Cos[θ[r]]
  }
```

where `r` and `ϕ` are polar coordinates and `θ[r]` is the polar angle of the spin as a function of radial coordinate. `θ[r]` is further parametrized as

```
θ[r] == Pi + ArcSin@Tanh[(r - c)/w] + ArcSin@Tanh[(r + c)/w]
```

where `c` and `w` are magnetic field dependent parameters (see the supplementary materials in the linked article for details).

---

For Example, this vector function is a good example,

```
k := {kx, ky}
d := 4
R1 := {1/Sqrt[3], 0}
R2 := {-1/(2*Sqrt[3]), 1/2}
R3 := {-1/(2*Sqrt[3]), -1/2}
f := Exp[I*k.R1] + Exp[I*k.R2] + Exp[I*k.R3]
Spin = Normalize@{(2*(-Sqrt[d^2/4 + Abs[f]^2] - d/2))/(Abs[f]^2 + (Sqrt[d^2/4 + Abs[f]^2] + d/2)^2) Re[f], (2*(Sqrt[d^2/4 + Abs[f]^2] + d/2))/(Abs[f]^2 + (Sqrt[d^2/4 + Abs[f]^2] + d/2)^2) Im[f], 1};
```

But if we code simply, the 3D vector plot is not so cool.

```
VectorPlot3D[Spin, {kx, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {ky, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {kz, -Pi,Pi},
VectorPoints -> {18, 18, 3}, VectorScale -> 0.05,
VectorColorFunction->Function[{kx, ky, kz, vx, vy, vz, n},
ColorData["ThermometerColors"][vz]],
RegionFunction -> ((-.1 < #3 < .1) &),
Boxed -> False,
Axes -> None]
```

How should we do?

[image]

Comment: "I found very beautiful 3d vector plot on the Internet." - then, link to it, please.

Comment: How can we tell you what graphics code is needed when you don't give us the mathematical context for the problem.

Comment: To m_goldberg, I edited and added the example of the vector function. I want to make the plot better.

Comment: Try using ``rmf2 = RegionMember[Disk[]]; VectorPlot3D[..., VectorPoints -> {30, 45, 3}, RegionFunction -> (rmf2[{#, #2}] && Abs[#3] < .1 &)]``  or something

Comment: To b3m2a1 Thank you for your comment. But I could not understand your point. I write your code. But nothing will be shown.

Comment: To b3m2a1 I wrote "rmf2 = RegionMember[Disk[]];
VectorPlot3D[Spin, {kx, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {ky, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {kz, -Pi, 
  Pi}, VectorPoints -> {30, 45, 3}, 
 RegionFunction -> (rmf2[{#, #2}] && Abs[#3] < .1 &)]" But I think it doesn't work.

Comment: To J.M. here is the link. http://www.learnabouttravelmaps.info/pics/g/germanene-zandvliet.html

Comment: @J.M. with some google-fu I found that this is a representation of a skyrmion [from FZ Jülich](https://www.fz-juelich.de/SharedDocs/Meldungen/PGI/PGI-1/EN/2016/2016-10-20-Skyrmion-Characterization.html) and [published in Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms13613). Some reading through the article can give us the proper parametrization of the spins.

Comment: @m_goldberg somehow I saw OP pinging J.M. and pinged him instead of you. \*shrug\*. Check out the links with the mathematical (physical, really) context if you like.

Comment: Thank you for finding and including the link, @LLlAMnYP. I hope the OP would do this him/herself for his/her future questions.

Comment: @J.M in this case it requires relevant domain knowledge plus access to Nature. That's why strangers from the internet are necessary :-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Nice "inverse problem". The angle distribution looks to me like a Gaussian.

```
ϕ[x_, y_, z_] := (Pi Exp[-Dot[{x, y}, {x, y}]/2] - Pi/2);
V[x_, y_, z_] := Evaluate[Simplify[ComplexExpand[-RotationMatrix[ϕ[x, y, z], {y, -x, 0}].{x, y, 0}/Sqrt[{x, y}.{x, y}]]]];
V[0, 0, z_] := {0, 0, -1};
R = Pi; 
P = Select[Flatten[Table[Table[{x, y, 0}, {y, -R, R, R/20}],{x, -R, R, R/20}], 1], X \[Function] -R <= X[[1]] - X[[2]] <= R];
P = Transpose[{{1, -1/2, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]/2, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}.Transpose[P]];
colfun[x_, y_, z_] := Evaluate[Simplify[ColorData["TemperatureMap"][(Pi/2 - ϕ[x, y, z])/Pi]]];
arrow[p1_, p2_] := {EdgeForm[], FaceForm[colfun @@ p1], Cone[{p1, p2}, 1/24]};
Show[
 Graphics3D[{arrow @@@ Transpose[{P, P + 1/4 V @@@ P}]}],
 PlotRange -> All,
 Lighting -> "Neutral",
 Boxed -> False
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: From [here](https://images.nature.com/original/nature-assets/ncomms/2016/161220/ncomms13613/extref/ncomms13613-s1.pdf) we can find the radial profile theta, where `Cos[theta]` is the z-component of the spin to be `Pi + ArcSin@Tanh[(r - c)/w] + ArcSin@Tanh[(r + c)/w]` where `c` and `w` are magnetic-field dependent parameters.