# Infinite expression 1/0 between v8 and v12.3

Tags: plotting

when i try the answere of Mr.Wizard from [How can I reproduce a beautiful 3D vector plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156157/how-can-i-reproduce-a-beautiful-3d-vector-plot/272517#272517)

```
ϕ[x_, y_, z_] := (Pi Exp[-Dot[{x, y}, {x, y}]/2] - Pi/2);
V[x_, y_, z_] := Evaluate[Simplify[ComplexExpand[-RotationMatrix[ϕ[x, y, z], {y, -x, 0}].{x, y, 0}/Sqrt[{x, y}.{x, y}]]]];
V[0, 0, z_] := {0, 0, -1};
R = Pi; 
P = Select[Flatten[Table[Table[{x, y, 0}, {y, -R, R, R/20}],{x, -R, R, R/20}], 1], X \[Function] -R <= X[[1]] - X[[2]] <= R];
P = Transpose[{{1, -1/2, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]/2, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}.Transpose[P]];
colfun[x_, y_, z_] := Evaluate[Simplify[ColorData["TemperatureMap"][(Pi/2 - ϕ[x, y, z])/Pi]]];
arrow[p1_, p2_] := {EdgeForm[], FaceForm[colfun @@ p1], Cone[{p1, p2}, 1/24]};
Show[
 Graphics3D[{arrow @@@ Transpose[{P, P + 1/4 V @@@ P}]}],
 PlotRange -> All,
 Lighting -> "Neutral",
 Boxed -> False
 ]
```

i get

```
 Power: Infinite expression 1/0^2 encountered.
```

as error message and there is one line missing:

[image: Skyrmion with defect line due to 1/0 infinite expression encountered]

Can you tell me, what i am doing wrong? It seems that he just used exactly that lines to produce the figure shown there. I am using Mathematica 12.3 while theirs seems to be v8.
Did something changed or am i just missing a definition?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Go to the `Evaluation` menu and choose `Quit Kernel` -> `Local` and then try this code again. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.Unfortunately this does not work. I get the same error message. 
Can i try something else?

Comment: The problem seems to be in the RotationMatrix, which sometimes gives the error, eg check the value of the function V for P[[21]]. Unfortunately, I am at work and I cannot dig into this any further, perhaps someone else can help.

Comment: MMA version13.1 does not show an error message, nor the missing line.

Comment: The hint with the rotation matrix seems to be right. If i add -RotationMatrix[\[Phi][x, y, z], {y + 0.0001, -x + 0.0001, 0}], no error occurs. For me this might be fine, however it more a workaround then a solution.

About the mathematica version: I can't rule out the possibility that one of my options is wrong and it's not the version itself. I'm using an university version where i can't change all options.

Comment: @DanielHuber I haven't checked MMA version 13.1, but I can confirm that on versions 9, 11.2 and 12.3 it does happen :-)

Comment: Add `// Simplify[#, Assumptions -> Element[{x, y, z}, Reals]] &`  at the end of definition  of V[x_,y_,z_] to get rid of Abs and so on, and it works fine !

Comment: By the way, you notice this, if you check step by step and use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed` in defintion of functions like V to see at once how they look like. Since you define V with Evaluate SetDelayed makes no sence.